# Class not registered Com Exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have third party DLL which I am using it in my application. when I run my application, I get Com Exception, Class not registered error.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {6A587E64-35FE-47EA-99F2-BDE40978D81D} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I know there are lot of duplicate question on this exception but none of the answers have helped me so far.

I have verified Class Id (Guid) is present in Registry entry.

I have tried to re register DLL by using Regsvr32.exe but it did not fix the issue. I have Win 7 machine and have tried re register from both type of regSvr32.exe. One located in Sytem32 and other one in SystemWow64.

I am running my application by targeting platform to Any CPU. Anyway, I have tried it by running as X86 and x64. X86 is will not work in my case as I have someother DLL which are 64 bit dll. My third party DLL is also 64 Bit dll.

Additional info:

This is existing application which works fine in XP. I am moving it to Win 7 and that is when I am facing the issue...Third Party DLL which I am talking about comes with installer...I just install it and refer the DLL...I have got 64 Bit version from third Party and have installed that in Win 7 Machine and only have changed reference to point to 64 Bit version DLL. I am sure that path I am referring to is correct..Not single line of code is changed apart from reference.

Any ideas on what next I could do to solve this problem

Comment: have you tried the dependency walker?

Comment: Nope...I have not...I will look into that...Do you have any link which can get me started?

Comment: Have tried manually browsing to the DLL from your IDE?

Comment: @downvoter...Pls let me know what is wrong in my question? I will improve it

Comment: @VivekVerma Yes...I am able to browse manually

Comment: Does anything else in your code indicate that the DLL has been referenced correctly? Are you using other types from it in any other way?

Comment: The dependency walker is a little tool which lets you analyse the dependencies of the component. It is possible that a dependent assembly cannot be loaded. You can get it here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Maybe there is a little confusion in the registry. If the assembly doesn't have a strong name, there can be conflicts between different versions of the dll. So maybe it's just this. Another problem could be, that the referenced dll in the registry entry, isn't located at the correct spot. One way to solve this, is to register the dll to the GAC, but this requires a strong name. But without any further diagnostic on your side, we are unable to detect the problem.

Comment: Is the third party dll a .net assembly? if so you might need regasm.exe to register it.

Comment: In Project properties, under build, is "Prefer 32- bit" checked?

Comment: @ jaymee I am referring the DLL correctly...See Additional Info in Question

Comment: @YoshSynergi so can I genereate strong name and register the dll in GAC?

Comment: @Stefan no, not a .Net Dll

Comment: @stamhaney i dont see this option

Comment: Right click the project under Visual Studio, Select the build  TAB, it is under Platform Target section. You need to remove the check if "Prefer 32-bit" is checked

Comment: To generate a strong name for a dll, you need to have the source code and recompile it with the strong name. That is a setting in Visual Studio as an example. But before you deal with this, I suggest clear your PC. Use the OLEComViewer of Visual studio, to see all references of your registered DLL and delete them all. You can also use CCLeaner for a little help. And then just set up everything nicely and retest it

Comment: @YoshSynergi I dont have the Source Code of that DLL. I will try your another suggestion